# How separate assignment of a value to a Variable and computational graph in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, theano

I have the following simple Theano code which I want to reproduce in TensorFlow:

```
import theano as th
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

x = T.vector()
c = th.shared(np.array([1.0, 2.0]))
y1 = x + c
c.set_value(np.array([10.0, 20.0]))
y2 = x + c
c.set_value(np.array([100.0, 200.0]))
print 'Y1:', th.function([x],y1)([0.0, 0.0])
print 'Y2:', th.function([x],y2)([0.0, 0.0])
```

In the above code I define two symbolic variables (`y1` and `y2`) that depend on `x` and `c` in the same way (`x + c`). The shared variable `c` at each point of time has a value. Whenever I evaluate `y1` and `y2` I always get identical values corresponding to the current value of `c`.

Now this is how I try to reproduce it in TensorFlow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

s = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
c = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0])
y1 = x + c
c = tf.assign(c, [10.0, 20.0])
s.run(c)
y2 = x + c
c = tf.assign(c, [100.0, 200.0])
s.run(c)
print 'Y1:', s.run(y1, feed_dict = {x : [0.0, 0.0]})
print 'Y2:', s.run(y2, feed_dict = {x : [0.0, 0.0]})
```

From the first point of view the structure of the code is identical (just different syntax). However, the behavior is different. As the output of this code I get:

```
Y1: [ 100.  200.]
Y2: [ 10.  20.]
```

The reason for the different values of `y1` and `y2` is clear to me: the first assignment to the `c` (`c = tf.assign(c, [10.0, 20.0])`) is done before the definition of `y2` and therefore this assignment becomes a part of the computational graph for `y2`.

So, now my question is whether it is possible in TensorFlow to set a value to a `Variable` without making the assignment a part of the computational graphs of all the symbolic variables that I define later.

In other words, I want to build a computational graph (in the above case the one for `y2`) that will take the current value of the variable `c` and ignore all the assignments that have been made to `c` before `y2` has been defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just shouldn't overwrite the Python variable *c* with the assign operation. You can assign a new value to *c* just by running the corresponding *assign* operation like this:

```
s = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
c = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0])
y1 = x + c
s.run(tf.assign(c, [10.0, 20.0]))
y2 = x + c
s.run(tf.assign(c, [100.0, 200.0]))

print 'Y1:', s.run(y1, feed_dict = {x : [0.0, 0.0]})  # Y1: [ 100.  200.]
print 'Y2:', s.run(y2, feed_dict = {x : [0.0, 0.0]})  # Y2: [ 100.  200.]
```

If for some reason you want to store the assign operation in a variable, just give it another name:

```
s = tf.Session()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
c = tf.Variable([1.0, 2.0])
y1 = x + c
a = tf.assign(c, [10.0, 20.0])
s.run(a)
y2 = x + c
a = tf.assign(c, [100.0, 200.0])
s.run(a)
print 'Y1:', s.run(y1, feed_dict = {x : [0.0, 0.0]})  # Y1: [ 100.  200.]
print 'Y2:', s.run(y2, feed_dict = {x : [0.0, 0.0]})  # Y2: [ 100.  200.]
```

Note that in both cases, `tf.assign(c, [10.0, 20.0])` is redundant as it will be immediately overwritten by the new value - I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, so please feel free to further elaborate your problem.